# Yet another javascript function scope question

Tags: javascript, scope

In this code, the ident and data variables are correct in the callback, but I don't know how to pass in the right i for each loop iteration.  I've tried reading up on functions and tried like 10 things, but alas, I must seek the wisdom of the stack.

```
function callback()
{
    $(ident).html( data.fields[i].value );
    $(ident).fadeTo('slow',1);
}

for(i=0;i<data.fields.length;i++)
{
    ident='#'+data.rID+'_'+data.fields[i].field;
    $(ident).fadeTo('slow',0,callback);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your "callback" function:

```
function callback(i) {
  return function() {
    $(ident).html( data.fields[i].value );
    $(ident).fadeTo('slow',1);
  };
}
```

Then in your loop:

```
$(ident).fadeTo('slow',0,callback(i));
```

This "callback" implementation *returns* the function that you'll pass to "fadeTo()".

Comment: need to make the `ident` variable local in the loop as well, to maintain the correct reference.. or change it to `$(this)` in the callback

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Gaby, the solution worked great as written ^^

Comment: It seems from the posted code that "ident" is global, or at least relatively global. It could indeed be passed in to the function, of course, as could "data".

Comment: I think the idea is that `ident` *is* global and uses the value of `i` in the for loop in its creation (of the selector string). As such, it is overwritten each time, and any reference to it in the `.callback()` will be to the version with the latest value of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to declare the callback function within the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was incorrect. Thanks to @Pointy for the heads-up.

This is similar to @Pointy's answer, but has different placement for the closure.

```
function callback(k) {
     $( this ).html( data.fields[k].value );
     $( this ).fadeTo('slow',1);
}

for(i=0;i<data.fields.length;i++) {
    (function(j) {
             ident='#'+data.rID+'_'+data.fields[j].field;
             $(ident).fadeTo('slow',0, function() { callback.call( this, j) });
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an anonymous function instead of the pointer to `callback`, so that you can pass in `i` to `callback`.

```
function callback(i, elem)
{
    $(elem).html( data.fields[i].value );
    $(elem).fadeTo('slow',1);
}

for(i=0;i<data.fields.length;i++)
{
    var ident='#'+data.rID+'_'+data.fields[i].field;
    $(ident).fadeTo('slow',0,function() { callback(i, this); });
}
```

Rather than making `ident` a global variable, it would be best to declare it (making it constrained to the current function's scope), and then use `this` in the callback to reference that element.

<del>If you're not using `callback` anywhere else, it may make sense to just put its implementation inside of the anonymous function, rather than defining it separately and calling out to it:</del>

```
for(i=0;i<data.fields.length;i++)
{
    ident='#'+data.rID+'_'+data.fields[i].field;
    $(ident).fadeTo('slow',0,function() { 
        $(ident).html( data.fields[i].value );
        $(ident).fadeTo('slow',1);
    });
}
```

The above example with the inline anonymous function doesn't work, because the reference to `i` is shared between the callbacks.

Comment: That will not work.  Each instance of that function will end up referencing the same value of "i" (that being "data.fields.length").

Comment: both examples are wrong.. first one because the callback still references the global `ident` variable and the parameter `i` will be the same. And the second both `i` and `ident` would be wrong in the callback..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  The inline example is definitely wrong (need to do like @Pointy and use a new function to give `i` a different scope).  I've updated the other one so that `ident` isn't a global variable, changing it to use `this` from the callback, instead.